# Fallback to specific intent within intent fulfillment

Tags: actions-on-google

When I checked the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/fulfillment#create_functions_to_handle_requests) for fulfillment error handling, I found this code:

```
const WELCOME_INTENT = 'Default Welcome Intent';
const NUMBER_INTENT = 'Input Number';
const NUMBER_ARGUMENT = 'num';

// you can add a fallback function instead of a function for individual intents
app.fallback((conv) => {
  // intent contains the name of the intent
  // you defined in the Intents area of Dialogflow
  const intent = conv.intent;
  switch (intent) {
    case WELCOME_INTENT:
      conv.ask('Welcome! Say a number.');
      break;

    case NUMBER_INTENT:
      const num = conv.arguments.get(NUMBER_ARGUMENT);
      conv.close(`You said ${num}`);
      break;
  }
});
```

I wonder if there is way to reference custom fallback intent (`my.intent.fallback`) (which is specific to intent, `my.intent`) directly (like some `conv.intent("my.intent.fallback")` api call) instead of `conv.ask('Welcome! Say a number.');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're mixing two concepts here.

The `app.fallback()` function is just meant to register a function that will be called if no other intent handler functions match. You shouldn't be using it to then monitor what intent was called.

You should be registering intent handler functions, including a named fallback intent, with something like

```
app.intent( 'fallback intent name', function(conv) )
```

Comment: I thought `app.fallback` can register intent to specific intent, more like try-catch flow for conversation. But it seems `app.fallback` is more global one like "Default Fallback Intent", is that right?

Comment: Sort of. As I say in the answer, if you want to register to a specific intent, use `app.intent()`. The function in `app.fallback()` is called if nothing that matches with `app.intent()` is available.

Comment: Cool, make sense!